# Elasticsearch - не получается создать анализатор

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Добрый день!
Только начал работать с эластиком. Проблема в том, что поиск не возвращает все варианты. Я так понимаю дело в том, что у меня не настроен анализатор russian (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#russian- analyzer)

Но у меня не получается его настроить.. Прошу помочь тем, кто в курсе как это сделать. Вот код создания индекса и наполнения его данными для поиска из БД:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts([ES_HOST])->build();

$params = [];
$params['index']  = ES_INDEX;

//Удаляю индекс
if($client->indices()->exists($params)){

    $response = $client->indices()->delete($params);

}
//Создаю запись
if(! $client->indices()->exists($params)){

    $index = $client->index([
        'index' => ES_INDEX,
        'type' => ES_TYPE,
        'id' => ES_ID,
        'body' => []
    ]);

}    

$sql = "SELECT id, `name` FROM salons_services";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Заполняю индекс значениями для поиска
foreach ($result as $row) {

    $params['body'][] = [
        'index' => [
            '_index' => ES_INDEX,
            '_type' => ES_TYPE,
        ]
    ];

    $params['body'][] = [
        'tableid' => $row['id'],
        'tablename' => trim($row['name'])
    ];

}

$responses = $client->bulk($params);
```

А потом этой функцией ищу IDники по слову

```
function searchES($word) {

    $client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts([ES_HOST])->build();

    $IDs = [];
    $params = [];
    $params['index'] = ES_INDEX;

    if ($client->indices()->exists($params)) {

        $params['type'] = ES_TYPE;
        $params['body']['query']['match']['tablename'] = trim($word);

        $result = $client->search($params);

        if ($result['hits']['total'] > 0) {

            $result = $result['hits']['hits'];

            foreach ($result as $val) {

                $k = $val['_source']['tableid'];
                $IDs[$k] = $k;

            }

        }

    }

    return $IDs;
}
```

Вот как я и сказал - возвращаются не все результаты... Я думаю, что надо подключить анализатор. Кто может подсказать, как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

При создании индекса нужно добавить маппинг, вот так:

```php
$config = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type'
];

$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

if ($client->indices()->exists(['index' => $config['index']]) ) {
    $result = $client->indices()->delete(['index' => $config['index']]);
}

$params = [
    'index' => $config['index'],
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 1,
            'number_of_replicas' => 1
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            $config['type'] => [
                '_source' => [
                    'enabled' => true
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    'tableid' => [
                        'type' => 'integer'
                    ],
                    'tablename' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'analyzer' => 'russian'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$result = $client->indices()->create($params);
```

Заполним тестовыми данными

```php
$result = $client->indices()->create($params);

$fixtures = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'На дворе трава'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'На траве дрова'], ];

$bulkData = ['body' => []];

foreach ($fixtures as $row) {
    $bulkData['body'][] = [
        'index' => [
            '_index' => $config['index'],
            '_type' => $config['type'],
            '_id' => $row['id']
        ]
    ];
    $bulkData['body'][] = [
        'tableid' => $row['id'],
        'tablename' => trim($row['name'])
    ]; }

$responses = $client->bulk($bulkData);
```

Пробуем найти по запросу "**трава**"

```php
$word = 'трава';
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = [
    'index' => $config['index'],
    'type' => $config['type'],
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'tablename' => $word
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$result = $client->search($params);
$ids = [];
if ($result['hits']['total'] > 0) {
    $result = $result['hits']['hits'];
    foreach ($result as $val) {
        array_push($ids, $val['_source']['tableid']);
    }
}

print_r($ids);
```

Видим результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)
```

Как видно, предложение со склоненным словом ***траве*** корректно нашлось.

Очень часто встроенного анализатора russian бывает мало и стоит присмотреться к плагину [elasticsearch-analysis-morphology](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology)